# Using GDB without debug symbols

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Assume the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(){
 //
}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Compiling whiteout `-g` I'm still able to set a breakpoint on `main` and `test` using GDB. 
How is that possible? Is it related to symbol tables?

```
(gdb) b test
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400512
```

Comment: Yes. Look at global symbols with nm. Use something like this: nm a.out | c++filt | grep " T "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you're missing.

C++ is built around the concept of compiling and then linking. As such, during the compilation stage, the compiler assumes that the current file is just one file in a more complex program that will be eventually linked together.

When you write:

```
void test(){
 //
}
```

The compiler has no choice but to assume that `test` is going to be called by code from another source file, and that will be compiled into a separate `.o` file. As such, it exports `test`'s symbol despite the fact that no debug symbols are defined.

To see this effect in action, try the following. First, mark `test` as static. If you compile with optimization, you will see that `test` is no longer visible to `gdb`. In fact, it is no longer even defined. The compiler inlines it away.

Another way of making this happen is by passing `g++` the `-fwhole-program` option. This option tells gcc to assume the current file being compile is the whole program, no other compilation unit will exist. This allows it, effectively, to treat all function and global definitions as static. Again, once you turn on optimizations, you will see that `test` is no longer visible to `gdb`.